# Let Value-string, Get value long VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a class module to store values for the position of buttons.  I will use the same function to add 3 buttons in a row, and so need to change the `.left` to position the button based on its type;

> Ie for a 'Create' button, I will look at the `.Left` value for Column A
>
> for a 'Update' button, I will look at the `.Left` value for Column B
>
> for a 'Destroy' button, I will look at the `.Left` value for Column C

I could add the case select in my code, but for readability i think it would sit better in the class module.

Currently I am trying to do the following- Relevant lines in class module:

```
Private pLeft As Long

Public Property Get Left() As Long
Left = pLeft
End Property

Public Property Let Left(strType As String)
    Select Case strType
        Case "Create"
            pLeft = pRange.Offset(0, 4).Left
        Case "Update"
            pLeft = pRange.Offset(0, 5).Left
        Case "Open"
            pLeft = pRange.Offset(0, 6).Left
    End Select
End Property
```

Relevant lines in module:

```
Dim Button As CButton
sub LetValueForLeft()
    Set Button = New CButton
    Button.Left = "Create"
End Sub
```

Heart breakingly I get the error :

[image]

I assume this is because I'm LETing with a string and GETing with a long, is there a way around this?

I have been using the really useful guide below, but it says nothing about this type of situation:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Let` and `Get` of a property need to be the same type.  If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you can always make `Left` a read-only property and use a method to initialize it:

```
'Class
Private pLeft As Long

Public Property Get Left() As Long
    Left = pLeft
End Property

Public Sub AssignLeft(strType As String)
    Select Case strType
        Case "Create"
            pLeft = pRange.Offset(0, 4).Left
        Case "Update"
            pLeft = pRange.Offset(0, 5).Left
        Case "Open"
            pLeft = pRange.Offset(0, 6).Left
    End Select
End Sub
```

You'd call it like this:

```
Set Button = New CButton
Button.AssignLeft "Create"
```